# Elements of Sequence Space $l^\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I'm studying functional analysis, specifically metric space section using Kreyzig's Introductory Functional Analysis with Application textbook.

It explains sequence space $l^\infty$ as a set $X$ that take the set of all bounded sequences of complex numbers; that is, every element of $X$ is a bounded complex sequence. The metric is defined by $$d(x,y) = \sup_{i\in N}|x_i - y_i|$$

My question is what constitute of elements of set $X$ in sequence space $l^\infty$. I thought of 2 specific examples but I'm not sure which one is right.

Case 1:

$x \in X$ and $y \in X$ such that: 
 $$ x = ({1}/{n^2})$$

$$ y = (1,1,1,1,1)$$

in this case,

$$d(x,y) = \sup_{i\in N}|{1}/{1^2}-1, {1}/{2^2}-1, {1}/{3^2}-1,...|$$

Case 2:

Set $X$ is set of $(a_n)$ such that $$(a_n) = ({1}/{n^2})$$

$x \in X$ and $y \in X$ such that say

$$x = (1/1^2, 1/2^2, 1/3^2...)$$ and
$$y = (1/100^2, 1/101^2, 1/102^2...)$$

The difference between $x$ and $y$ in this case is they start indexing at different starting point.

In this case,
$$d(x,y) = \sup_{i\in N}|{1}/{1^2}-{1}/{100^2}, {1}/{2^2}-{1}/{101^2}, {1}/{3^2}-{1}/{102^2},...|$$

I been thinking about it but couldn't wrap my mind on which case is the book referring to. Wonder if someone could point it out to me.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you expand a little more on what you mean? $\ell^\infty$ is the space of bounded sequences, all of the sequences you named are in $\ell^\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, start a little further back:

A *sequence* in $\Bbb C$ is just a function $a : \Bbb N \to \Bbb C$.

For $n \in \Bbb N$, we commonly denote $a(n)$ by $a_n$. And often we denote $a$ itself by $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ or just by $\{a_n\}$ for short. We can also think of $a$ as an infinite tuple: $a = (a_0, a_1, a_2, ...)$.

A sequence is *bounded* if there is a real number $M$ such that for all $n, |a_n| < M$.

So $\ell^\infty = \{a \mid a$ is a bounded sequence in $\Bbb C\}$.

Now lets look at your sequences:

(I have to be careful here since I define sequences as being for all of $\Bbb N$ and am further using the definition of $\Bbb N$ that includes $0$.)

(1) $x : \Bbb N \to \Bbb C : n \mapsto \begin{cases}0& n=0\\1/n^2 & n > 0\end{cases}$.

Since $|x_n| = x_n < 2$ for all $n$, $x_n$ is a bounded sequence. Therefore $x \in \ell^\infty$.

(2) $y : \Bbb N \to \Bbb C : n \mapsto 1$.

For all $n$, $|y_n| = 1 < 2001$. Therefore $y$ is a bounded sequence. So $y \in \ell^\infty$.

Finally, your third sequence (the 2nd $x$ is the same as the first) is

(3) $\displaystyle y : \Bbb N \to \Bbb C : n \mapsto \frac 1{(n + 100)^2}$.

Since $n + 100 > 1$, we have $1/(n+100)^2 < 1$ for all $n$. Thus $|y_n| = y_n < 1$. So $y$ is a bounded sequence and so $y \in \ell^\infty$.

---

So all the sequences you gave are just examples of sequences in $\ell^\infty$.

You talk about sets "$X$", but have not provided any understandable definition for them, so I cannot address what you meant by it.

Comment: Thank you! I think your explaination has helped me to better understand what constitute elements of sequence space $\ell^\infty$