# Understanding the Proof of Completeness of $c$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complete-spaces

I'm studying the proof that space $c$ is complete.

The space c consists of all convergent sequences $x=(\mathcal{E}_j)$ of complex numbers, with the metric induced from the space $l^\infty$.

Proof. $c$ is a subspace of $l^\infty$ and we show that $c$ is closed in $l^\infty$.

We consider any $x=(\mathcal{E}_j)\in\bar c$, closure of $c$. Hence, there are $x_n=(\mathcal{E}_j^{(n)})\in c$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$. Hence, given any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that for $n \ge N$ and all $j$ we have $$\vert \mathcal{E}_j^{(n)} - \mathcal{E}_j \vert \le  d(x_n,x) \lt \frac \epsilon 3, $$
in particular, for $n=N$ and all $j$.

I have the following questions, wonder if someone could help me with them.

Questions:

1) An example of $x=(\mathcal{E}_j)\in\bar c$. For simplicity, I think of a sequence $\{1,1,...,1\}$. I don't know with certainty if this is correct.

2) An example of $x_n=(\mathcal{E}_j^{(n)})\in c$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$. If $x \in \bar c = \{1,1,...,1\}$. Then, what is an example of $x_n$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$?

Thank you!

Comment: I reviewed the question that I asked before on this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169397/elements-of-sequence-space-l-infty/2169572#2169572. I think I have the answer for the first question above. However, I'm still trying to visualize answer to question #2. $x$ an element of $\bar c$. So, $x$ is a sequence. I'm trying to visualize $x_n$ a sequence itself approches $x$

Answer (score 0):

Isn't $(1,1,1,\dots)$ a convergent sequence and thus is in $c$?

To show $c$ is closed in $l^\infty$, suppose $x^{(k)} \to x$ where $x^{(k)} = (x_n^{(k)})_n$ and $x = (x_n)_n$ are sequences. Let $L_k = \lim_n x_n^{(k)}$. Then, since $(x^{(k)})_k$ is Cauchy in $l^\infty$, it's easy to see that $(L_k)_k$ is Cauchy and thus converges to some complex number $L$.

We show $x_n \to L$. Take $\epsilon > 0$. Take $k$ large so that $|L-L_k| < \epsilon$ and then $||x-x^{(k)}||_\infty < \epsilon$. Then for $n$ large enough, $|x^{(k)}_n-L_k| < \epsilon$ and so $|x_n-L| \le |x_n-x^{(k)}_n|+|x^{(k)}_n-L_k|+|L_k-L| < 3\epsilon$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: $x^{(k)} = (x_n^{(k)})_n$ and $x = (x_n)_n$ are sequences. Got that. One of my main problems is that I'm not certain that I understand some of the unfamiliar notations. 1) what does $k$ here denote? Does it mean one specific instance of an arbitrary sequence? 2) $x^{(k)} = (x_n^{(k)})_n$ and $x = (x_n)_n$  --- why is there $n$ inside the bracket and $n$ outside of the bracket? Normally, $n$ of the inside brackets denote the n-th element of the sequence. 3) if $x=(1,1,1,\dots)$, then I imagine $x^{(k)}$ as a sequence where each elements approaches each element of $x$ which is 1 in this case.

Comment: $k$ is a positive integer. I write $(x_n)_n$ to represent the sequence $(x_1,x_2,\dots)$. It is shorthand for $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. So $(x_n^{(k)})_n = (x_1^{(k)},x_2^{(k)},\dots)$.

Comment: And yes. Each $x^{(k)}$ is a sequence and the elements of $x^{(k)}$ approach $1$ uniformly in $k$.

Comment: If $x=(1,1,1,\dots)$, and say $x^{(k)}= \{\frac {1} {n+k}\}_{n=1}^\infty$. So, say for $k=1$, $x^{(k)}=x^{(1)}=\{\frac {1} {n+1}\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Then, $\vert x^{(1)} - x \vert = \{1-\frac {1} {1+1}, 1-\frac {1} {2+1},1-\frac {1} {3+1}, \dots \}$. Let's say for a given $\epsilon= \frac 1 {100}>0$, then in this instance for all $k>100$ $$ \vert x^{(k)}_n - x_n \vert \le d(x^{(k)},x) = \sup_n^\infty \vert x^{(k)}_n - x_n \vert \le \epsilon = \frac 1 {100}$$ Could I confirm that I have it right? Thank you!

Comment: That's exactly right!